# Como puedo buscar un dato en un array?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

buenos dias.

El dia de hoy vengo con este problema:

Quiero  filtrar un dato mediante el parametros que reciba, tengo este array

```js
let dataCountries = [
  {
    Country: 'Finland',
    Slug: 'finland',
    ISO2: 'FI',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Saint-Barthélemy',
    Slug: 'saint-barthélemy',
    ISO2: 'BL',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Spain',
    Slug: 'spain',
    ISO2: 'ES',
  },
];
```

Los parametros lo puede recibir de esta manera: "Finland", "spain", "bl",

Y tengo filtrar los datos con el parametro que reciba para sacar solamente el value  "Country" del array.

Yo lo hice de esta manera, pero siento que no es un codigo ideal:

```js
let dataCountries = [
  {
    Country: 'Finland',
    Slug: 'finland',
    ISO2: 'FI',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Saint-Barthélemy',
    Slug: 'saint-barthélemy',
    ISO2: 'BL',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Spain',
    Slug: 'spain',
    ISO2: 'ES',
  },
];

const hola =  (strinp) =>
  dataCountries.filter((i) => i.Country === strinp).length 
    ? dataCountries.find((i) => i.Country === strinp[0].toUpperCase() + strinp.slice(1))
    : dataCountries.filter((i) => i.Slug === strinp).length 
    ? dataCountries.find((i) => i.Slug === strinp)
    : dataCountries.find((i) => i.ISO2 === strinp.toUpperCase());

console.log(hola('spain')['Country']);
console.log(hola('Saint-Barthélemy')['Country']);
console.log(hola('FI')['Country']);
```

"Pueden ejecutar el codigo"

Comment: ¿Debes revisar si el dato del método coincide con alguna de las propiedades de los objetos en el array?

Comment: Estás seguro de los parámetros? Porque bl es un iso2, y el resto puede ser country o slug...

Answer (score 1):

Comparación con `obj.Country` parece innecesario porque Slug se deriva de Country.

Puedo imaginar que el algoritmo `Country -> Slug` es `country.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-")`. (reemplazar espacios con guiones)

Por ejemplo:

```
Spain -> spain
South Korea -> south-korea
New Zealand -> new-zealand
```

Solo necesitas transformar (normalizar) el input para coincidir con la forma de tus datos.

```js
const countries = [
  {
    Country: 'Finland',
    Slug: 'finland',
    ISO2: 'FI',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Saint-Barthélemy',
    Slug: 'saint-barthélemy',
    ISO2: 'BL',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Spain',
    Slug: 'spain',
    ISO2: 'ES',
  },
];

function slug(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-")
}

function buscar(key) {
  const country = countries.find(c => {
    // Primero, vamos a comprobar si input key es un slug o pais.
    // Ojo que vamos a hacerlo con uno comparacion porque
    // nuestro slug() funcion va a unificar ambos casos:
    //     slug("New Zealand") -> "new-zealand"
    //     slug("new-zealand") -> "new-zealand"
    return slug(key) === c.Slug || 
        // Si el slug comparacion falló, el input
        // tiene que ser un 2-digit codigo de pais. facil:
        key.toUpperCase() === c.ISO2
  })
  // Si encontrado, extraer el nombre de pais
  return country ? country.Country : null
}

console.log(buscar("spain")) // "Spain"
console.log(buscar("bl")) // "Saint-Barthélemy"
console.log(buscar("finland")) // "Finland"
console.log(buscar("noexiste")) // null
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución para esto es usar flujos sobre tus arreglos.

```js
let dataCountries = [{
    Country: 'Finland',
    Slug: 'finland',
    ISO2: 'FI',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Saint-Barthélemy',
    Slug: 'saint-barthélemy',
    ISO2: 'BL',
  },
  {
    Country: 'Spain',
    Slug: 'spain',
    ISO2: 'ES',
  },
]

const termino = 'BL'.toLowerCase()

const resultado = dataCountries
  .map(x => {
 //Convertimos todo a una cadena de busqueda
    var cadenaBusqueda = x.Country
    .concat(x.Slug)
    .concat(x.ISO2)
    //Convertimos todo a minusculas para no tener que lidiar
    // con tamanos diferentes
    .toLowerCase()

    return {
     //Guardamos el objeto original en una cadena
      objeto: x,
      //Anexamos un parametro de cadena para el siguiente
      // flujo de manera que podamos filtrar. 
      cadenaBusqueda: cadenaBusqueda
    
    }
  })
  //Filtramos los datos con la ayuda de la cadena que concatenamos
  .filter(x=> x.cadenaBusqueda.includes(termino))
  //Retornamos todo a su estrucutra o solo la propiedad country. 
  .map(x=> x.objeto.Country)

  
  console.log(resultado)
```

## Mas informacion

[tuArreglo.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

[tuArreglo.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

[tuTextoOArreglo.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)